# Add a description field for my selected "top answers" in careers

Tags: feature-request, answers, jobs

I appreciate having the "Top Answers" section on the careers site, allowing me to highlight the answers I think would be most useful to a prospective employer. What would make it even better, though, is adding an optional description field so that I can point out why it is of interest and what makes it unique rather than forcing the reader to do a lot of work to appreciate it. As it stands one has to navigate to the question, digest both the question and the answer, and compare it to all the other answers before finally being able to conclude, "Oh, this answer ***is*** good!". That is way too much work--most people will have neither the time nor the inclination to do it.

Rather than go on ad naseum, I think an example makes my point clearly--compare my "before" and "after" below:

[image: adding hint to top answer]

Now **there** is a reason to click that link!

Comment: this reminds me of "edit" feature that is there in careers profile for articles and books, allowing one provide a summary of what's there. Do you mean something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I remember a conversation about this on meta at one point, but I cannot seem to find it now.  I do remember the result of it was that what you think is important is not necessarily what people viewing your profile think is important about a some answer you gave.  We also thought if you had something to point out about an answer in particular, it's more of a service to add emphasis and otherwise refine the actual answer on it's home site than to just highlight something on Careers.

Comment: **"add emphasis and otherwise refine the actual answer on it's home site"** sounds just the way to go. This improves both the _home site_ and Careers profile

Comment: I respectfully disagree with you both. Typically the one-line comment I would add (as in my example) is _already in the actual answer_. Consider if you were a recruiter having a stack of 500 resumes. Are you _really_ going to read them all? No, you will scan them to identify a smaller, targeted set to read. Same principle applies: if I were a recruiter I would not click through every link on a person's Careers profile until I can identify a reason to. A question title in Top Answers gives (almost) no information about the person nor his/her answer! A short description provides this vital info.